# Load new values from another Python script

Tags: python, file

I have a device which I am controlling in a `for` loop. I would like to check every iteration if a `.txt` file has changed. If it has I want to read values and send them to the device. I am checking if file was updated like this:

```
os.stat("myfile.txt").stat.st_mtime
```

This is working fine when I manually open file, write values and save file.
I want to change values by another Python script which will be run by another process. In this other script I write values to the `.txt` file like this:

```
text_file = open("myfile.txt", 'w') 
text_file.write("\n0\n0\n0")
text_file.close()
```

When I call `open()`, `st_mtime` changes and I load nothing because text file is empty. How to deal with this? Are there other approaches besides a text file to set new values by another Python process?

Comment: Exchanging objects between processes <https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#:~:text=method%20does%20work.-,Exchanging%20objects%20between%20processes,-%C2%B6>

Comment: When you are reading the new data do you open the file for reading? `open(...,'r')`?

Comment: @wwii Yes i do.

Comment: Is your problem that your other process is not writing anything to the file or is the problem that `st_mtime` changes even if the file contents haven't changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used 3 files. I check if 3th files st_mtime has changed. I write new values to a second file, and than open and close 3th file. St_mtime of the 3th file changes so i load values from second file safely. :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could try an alternate way to check if the contents have changed, by checking for MD5 checksum for example.

```
import hashlib
..
my_hex = hashlib.md5(text_file.read()).hexdigest()
```

You can now monitor `my_hex` every iteration to check if your file contents have changed.